# How to write on a new line using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I'm setting up a script and I need to write on a new line for each increment of my for loop.

For the moment, I write my headers then I write on the next line but at each increment it erases my line to write the new data.

```py
headers = [['Name', 'Age']]
for i in range(10):
   line = [[str(name), str(age)]]
   with open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
       writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
       writer.writerows(headers)
       writer.writerows(line)
       writer.writerows('\n')
```

I'm trying to set the next line with `writer.writerows('\n')` but it didn't works.

I think that the second line is always overwritten but I don't know how to jump to the next line using my loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your loop be inside your `with`, not the other way around?

Comment: Yup. It should be `for` inside `with` and `headers` just before the `for`. `writerows` writes a whole row, so `\n` is not needed.

Comment: I'm confused as to why `writerows` is being used at all here. Just remove the extra `list` wrapping from `headers` and `line`, and you can call plain `writerow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put your code the other way around:

You open your file for writing (not appending) each time the loop executes, each time writing headers again and writing one row only.

`writerows`, as the name suggests, write full rows, so new line isn't needed. And it writes row_s_, so you had to make headers and lines with `[[` and `]]`. Use `writerow` to write a single one.

```
headers = ['Name', 'Age']
with open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for i in range(10):
        line = [str(name), str(age)]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Why did your `writer.writerows('\n')` didn't work? Because as I said above, it's row_s_, it expects an iterable. It could work as `writer.writerows(['\n'])` (made a single-element list) or `writer.writerow('\n')` (row, not rows).

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file only once, then use the loop.

```
headers = [['Name', 'Age']]
with open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(headers) #I assume you want the header only once
    for i in range(10):
       line = [[str(name), str(age)]]
       writer.writerows(line)
       writer.writerows('\n')
```

Comment: If you're moving the `open` out of the loop, probably best to move the creation of `writer` out of the loop while you're at it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, I was still editing the code... Thanks for having noticed it.

Comment: I didn't find a way to use this method. I finally find a solution, simply by adding lines on a list and then write it on the csv file at the end. Like: `list.append(line)` and then `writer.writerows(list)`